# Webpack 4 unwanted libraries when importing 'sjcl'.

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4

I've created a simple webpack 4 demo-project which doesn't have any configuration. I added a simple index.js that just prints out a simple line and all works well. A 900 byte main.js is generated as expected.

However, when i require the 24kb library 'sjcl' (has 0 dependencies) and then execute the build, a 400kb file is generated. I've used an analyzer to  Any ideas onto what is going on?

It's like webpack is importing a ton of dependencies to handle this library. How can i mitigate this?

index.js

```
require("sjcl");
console.log("hello world");
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "js-demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "sjcl": "1.0.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "4.16.5",
    "webpack-cli": "3.1.0"
  }
}
```

> WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the
>   recommended size limit (244 KiB). This can impact web performance.
>   Assets:   main.js (323 KiB)

Below is my analyzer:
https://pastebin.com/iguWmmaS

Answer (score 0):

Looks like webpack adds a browser compatible version of the node crypto module to the bundle, thus significantly increasing the size. To prevent Webpack from doing this, you can use the below option for webpack to ignore the library.

```
module: {
            noParse: [
                /sjcl\.js$/,
            ]
         }
```